# Trying to check an image whether it is tapped in if condition in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i'm Trying to check an image whether it is tapped or not in if condition in UWP
but don't know how to achieve.
Any help would be appreciated.Given below if(pause.Tapped) is giving error
xaml

```
<Image x:Name="Pause" Source="ABCD/Pause.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="Music"
                   Margin="17,0,0,0" Tapped="PauseTap"
               Width="40" Height="40"/>
```

C# code

```
public ABCD()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            LoopStart();
        }

        public async void LoopStart()
        {           
            if(Pause.Tapped)
}
```

Comment: What is your goal to achieve, besides detecting tapping in an other method? I am asking because I think you want something and try to solve it this way. Do you know about message handlers? And threading?

Comment: Maybe you should to change `Image` to `Button` like pause and handle `Click` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're line `if(Pause.Tapped)` won't work because you're treating an event like a property. Instead you can use an event handler to set a flag to break the loop.
Something like this:

```
private bool _isPaused = false;

ctor() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DoLooping();
}

private void DoLooping()
{
    // This will keep looping forever
    while (true)
    {
        if (!_isPaused)
        {
            // do things here if not paused...
        }
    }
}

void PauseTap(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{       
    _isPaused = !_isPaused; // This will allow the pause button to act as a toggle
}
```

Comment: I used your code example but on clicking pause image it is not going to execute which i want to execute on clicking pause